# java annotation: OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper or CallSuper

Tags: java, android, annotations

I'm writing an Android app and find myself a need to annotate that a method must be called by it's overriding method (`super.someMethod()`).

However, I find two annotations: `OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper` and `CallSuper`, provided in `javax.annotation` and `android.support.annotation` respectively.

My questions are:

1. What's the difference between these two annotations (except for their name and provider)? (I didn't see any difference, anyway.)
2. If there is no difference, why does Android create a separate annotation?
3. In general, which one is more preferred and why?